# can I create an array of items in lightning event if Yes, how do I get this array in JS controller?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="AddOrderEvent">
    <aura:attribute name="DishInOrder" type="DishInOrder__c[]"/>
</aura:event>


  var newDishInOrder = component.get('v.NewDishInOrder');
  newDishInOrder.Dish__c = dish;
  var orderEvent = component.getEvent("addOrder");
  var orders = orderEvent.getParams("DishesInOrder");
  orders.push(newDishInOrder);
  orderEvent.setParams({
        "DishesInOrder": orders
  });
  console.log(newDishInOrder.Dish__c);
  orderEvent.fire();
```

This code does not work.

Comment: Your question is too broad and it is not exactly clear on what you need to do or where you're stuck.

Comment: Yes you can create and pass around arrays.

Comment: I need to take an array from event to add a value there and save it back.

Comment: and where exactly are you stuck? what problem are you facing. What you are attempting is very well documented and there are even Code snippets for you to be able to test out by yourself. Usually, mentioning that X code doesnt work, is not really an accurate problem description. based on what I see, you should probably head to Trailhead(s) and complete the lighning component Modules, which explain the basics and will provide you with exercises to ramp up your skills

Comment: var orderEvent = component.getEvent("addOrder"); -here event get I
            var orders = orderEvent.getParam("DishesInOrder"); -here I get the parameters of the event that is an array
            orders.push(newDishInOrder); -here I want to do add a new object to this array but shows the error [Cannot read property 'path' of undefined]

Comment: the module that you were advised to go through I went through and revised many times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code sample, you are not setting the right event parameter.
Your attribute is named `DishInOrder` in the event markyp but you are setting `DishesInOrder` in your JavaScript code:

```
orderEvent.setParams({
    DishesInOrder: orders
});
```

Comment: Quotes not necessary: `orderEvent.setParams({
    DishesInOrder: orders
});`